# Relationship between energy of radiation and energy of oscillating particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, harmonic-oscillator

We know that radiation is created from oscillating particle. Thus the oscillation frequency becomes the radiation frequency which determines its energy: E =hf. But for the case of quantum harmonic oscillator, we know that the energy is quantized: E = hw(n + 1/2). But because energies and frequency has to match, the quantized terms seems to be causing a discrepancy. So how could this be reconciled?

Comment: What is the discrepancy you are referring to?

Comment: that (n + 1/2) term changes the amount of energy given same frequency. This seems like total energy of the oscillator given by the Hamiltonian does not match the energy carried away by the radiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In quantum mechanics radiation (photon) is generated when a system moves from one energy state to another. And the energy of the photon is equal to the energy difference of the two states. There is no oscillating dipole.

So in the case of a harmonic oscillator, when the system goes from say $n=3$ to $n=0$ state, the energy released is $3\hbar\omega$ where $\omega =\sqrt{k/m}$. Thus the emitted photon has a frequency of $3\omega$.

Because the energy states are stationary states, there is no oscillation occurring and $\omega$ is just a constant that describes your system.

However, to see how this constant of the system somehow matches with the frequency of the EM wave made up of a collection of these photons, look up [coherent states.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by user3518839none should stress that light is composed of particles , called photons, but photons are not light, in the way bricks may make a building but they are not a building.

[The wave function of a photon](https://arxiv.org/ftp/quant-ph/papers/0604/0604169.pdf) is the solution of the quantized Maxwell's equation. A superposition of many photon wavefunctions make up the light with the frequency $ν$ , but the [individual photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light) are elementary point particles, with zero mass and the spin pointing into their direction of motion  , +1 or -1.

The sinusoid wavefunction of a photon is not measurable, it is the probability of seeing one photon that "waves". In confluence with innumerable other photons of the same energy builds up the classical wave which carries energy accros space in a sinusoid form.